# Unable to access mobile camera within browser using media stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am trying to open camera within mobile browser using localMediaStream and it is working just fine in firefox browser in Linux and chrome browser in a phone(Micromax). but apart from that, it isn't working anywhere. 
the web page isn't asking for camera permissions in any other mobile devices.

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.msGetUserMedia);

var video;
var webcamStream;

function startWebcam() {
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: false
    }, function(localMediaStream) {
      video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      webcamStream = localMediaStream;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
  }
}

function stopWebcam() {
  webcamStream.stop();
}
```

Help and suggest the better a way to do this.

Comment: You have first of all verified whether those “other mobile devices” (resp. their browsers) support this feature, right?

Comment: I'm trying a generic way to do this. Is there any other method I can use to achieve this ?